# Mapping pojo entities with web service client generated artifacts

Tags: java, web-services

I have create a simple webservice in java returning a POJO. I'm using this POJO from a separate JAR. When i create a client of this project, netbeans creates its own version of POJO  through the wsimport utility. Obviously both POJOs (from jar and auto-generated) are different because of different package names.

Is there any way i can map these two automatically?

Comment: Can anybody answer this question please?

Comment: @alex still to find a better solution. Used  helper methods for copying the auto generated class to original class

Comment: It seems I found a solution. Find it below.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some mapper for that, for example [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). Read about its configuration, it should help you.